# Can't set hotkeys for brackets in Sublime Text 3

Tags: configuration, sublimetext3, hotkeys, brackets

I don't like that printing brackets is so uncomfortable at a standard keyboard. I tried to fix it in Sublime Text 3. "Insert" command just inserts text, without any features that Sublime Text has for brackets, like auto-closing. Is it possible to reconfigure work with brackets to alternative hotkey?

This is how I have set hotkeys.

```
[
    {"keys": ["alt+j"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "("}},
    {"keys": ["alt+k"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "["}},
    {"keys": ["alt+l"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "{"}},
]
```

Comment: Have you looked in the default key bindings? The bindings for these characters is more involved than just a simple insert; you could duplicate the main ones and alter the keys